# Обработка данных с датчиков и занесение их в БД

Tags: база-данных, php

Есть датчики температурные.

Они каждый интервал времени снимают температуру.заносят эти данные в бд . А в этой бд хранятся еще данные эталонных значений, с которыми надо сравнить мои значения и после вывести результат. Там мол здоров, или там лихорадка.

Причем снятые мною данные надо еще как то преобразовывать (в ряды Фурье можно разложить сказал преподаватель (зачем, правда, я не понял)). Причем надо сделать привязку всего этого к вебу. Вот с чего начать? Что почитать? И в каких прогах делать лучше?

Comment: наверное начать нужно с курса данного преподавателя и списка рекомендуемой им литературы.

Comment: да он не вел у меня .
и литературы тоже не дал никакой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. научиться получать данные с датчиков
2. разработать БД
3. научиться заносить полученные данные в БД в реальном времени
4. разработать веб страничку, которая выводит данные

для веба посоветую php

БД MySql (т.е. БД с которой сервак веба работает)

**UPD**
На счет ряда Фурье:

> ряд Фурье прозрачным образом ведёт
> себя при дифференцировании,
> интегрировании, сдвиге функции по
> аргументу и свёртке функций.
> (из [Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5))

грубо говоря, дальше будет легче работать, сравнивать, и проводить анализа этих графиков.

---

> научиться заносить полученные данные в БД в реальном времени

т.е. датчик работает, и допустим каждые 10 секунд снимает данные. В реальном времени означает, что он как снимет данные, сразу их отправляет в БД твоей системы. Для этого например можешь написать веб-страничку, которая принимает данные (по GET или POST запросу), и заносит их в свою БД. А отправлять туда данные можно из любой программы (отправлять запрос).

Comment: спасибо!
а какие БД выбрать?
и не понятно зачем это разложение в ряды Фурье??
и что значит заносить в реальном времени?

Comment: добавил к ответу, можешь почитать )

Comment: от души!
буду разбираться!спасибо за наводки!

Comment: кстате пока разбирался ,возник вопрос:
вот допустим собрал я все необходимые данные для построения графика.
построил этот график.и есть эталонный.вот как их сравнить между собой?на процент соответствия ?или может сравнивать и не графиками а числовыми данными?что посоветуете?какие методы лучше использовать

Comment: надо числа сравнивать, массив данных. Например берете разницу эталона и твоего графика, получаешь новый график. А вообще, методов сравнений полно, например, еще можно дифференцировать, получить у каждого графика изменение во времени (например 1час: +10, 2час: +3, 3час: -10 ...) и сравнивать уже это самое изменение во времени. можно как вы предложили на процент... А вообще, если интересно, можем пообщаться лично, помогу разобраться как смогу )

Comment: да, вк хотябы ) вечером, когда дома буду, добавлюсь

Comment: http://vk.com/baburkinda
добавляйся)
или напиши ссылку на себя